# wc -l against all files within an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a path to an `s3` bucket that contains many files. Using `aws-cli`, is there a command that will allow me to read all the files and `| wc -l` against the output? I am trying to count all the lines for all the files within an `s3` bucket

Comment: Remember that "wc" needs to read the file to count its content e.g. the file needs to be downloaded.

Comment: not necesarily, you can output the file without downloading. Example: `aws s3 cp "$FILENAME" -`

Answer (score 2):

Recurse list into the bucket, and run the copy command to `stdout`. This helps as the file is not downloaded on the machine.

You can follow the below command, working for me:

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://bucket-name/ | while read FILENAME; do
 echo "$FILENAME"
 if [ "$(aws s3 cp "$FILENAME" - | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "0"
 else
  aws s3 cp "$FILENAME" - | wc -l
 fi
done | paste -d, - -
```

Output:

```
s3://bucket-name/a.txt,343
s3://bucket-name/b.txt,0
```

If you're trying to get the count of gzipped files in AWS, use 'zcat' like this:  aws s3 cp "$FILENAME" - | zcat | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by listing all your S3 buckets -

```
aws s3 ls
```

For listing objects in a specific bucket, try -

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
```

And to answer your question, you can do -

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.txt - | wc -l
```

For more awscli S3 commands, check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html).

Comment: Your command will only count the number of files and not the number of lines, words, chars, etc. within the files.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Linux Command, List the files in a directory in s3 and count line by line using wc -l

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/ | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could use [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) to count rows in Parquet/CSV/gzip/bzip2 files using Python/boto3.

```
sql_stmt    = """SELECT count(*) FROM s3object S"""   
req_fact =s3.select_object_content( 
    Bucket  = bucket_name, 
    Key     = s3_key, 
    ExpressionType  = 'SQL', 
    Expression      = sql_stmt, 
    InputSerialization={'Parquet': {}}, 
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': { 
                'RecordDelimiter': os.linesep, 
                'FieldDelimiter': colsep}}, 
     
)
```

Note, that you can apply it only to Parquet and CSV files and it will not work on raw unstructured logs.
Check [async counter](https://github.com/pydemo/S3-parquet-files-row-counter/blob/main/async_counter.py) for full Python sample.